# Forward SSL Client certificate using php_curl

Tags: php, curl, openssl, client-certificates

I have the following setup:

There are 2 servers that require an SSL client certificate. 
The certificate is used for authentication.

A user (using his browser) will do a request to Server1, with his client certificate.
So far, so good.
Now, what I want to do:
Server1 will do a request to Server2, parse that response, and return it to the user.

Server1 does the request with php_curl.
I want Server1 to pass the original client certificate (of the user) to Server2 (which will verify the user, ..). Server1 is then posting 'on behalf of' the user.

Is this possible?

Apache has ExportCertData SSLOption enabled.
I already tried to add the following headers to the curl options (figuring this was about the same as Apache proxy setup with client certs):

```
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_I_DN: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_I_DN'];
$headers[] = "SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU: ".$_SERVER['SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_V_START: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_V_START'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_V_END: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_V_END'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_CERT: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'];
$headers[] = "SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY: ".$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY'];
$headers[] = "SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION: ".$_SERVER['SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION'];
$headers[] = "SSL_SERVER_I_DN: ".$_SERVER['SSL_SERVER_I_DN'];
$headers[] = "SSL_SERVER_CERT: ".$_SERVER['SSL_SERVER_CERT'];
```

but no luck with those.

Comment: IIRC SSL is end-to-end, you can't proxy it.

Comment: Apache can do proxy on SSL connections. Also, I'm ok with setting up a new SSL connection, just, with the same certificate, or is that not possible? I don't quite want to proxy the request either, I'm doing another request, just with the same cert..

Comment: Client certificates? Then they would not be working as intended any longer. You should try to man in the middle attack the clients connection to make it more transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't pass a request with an original client certificate unless you have that certificate with keys and such on hand. This is how SSL works.

If you're running both of the servers you could verify client certificate on Server1 and pass verified information on the Server2 by means of custom headers or whichever you find suits best.

If you're not responsible for the second server, well, no luck for you, because making MITM attacks simple was not one of intentions of SSL creators.

Comment: That is my backup solution. I know it works, but I'd prefer to do authentication of the user based on his SSL cert, rather than another (even though it's trusted) server pasisng me the users' CN as a string parameter. I understand the main-in-the-middle atack danger, but the same problem would also exist with Apache proxy, no?

Comment: Sure with certain effort you can pass *undecrypted* requests like Apache mod_proxy does. But I cannot find any special purpose in this.